# How to make an SKSpriteNode not fall (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I have an `SKSpriteNode` variable called `lazer` in which when you tap the screen of the simulator it gets shot upwards, however when you let go, it falls down. I would like it to not fall down when not touching the screen anymore. I have used the `physicsBody` property `affectedByGravity` and set it to false but it does not work, as shown below:

```
lazer.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you add `laser` and shot it?

Comment: have you applied this `physicsBody` to `laser`? SKSpriteNodes do not init with physicsBodys i believe. You must apply them to each node as they are created

Comment: var lazer = SkSpriteNode() I then add a texture to it.  
        lazer.physicsBody?.dynamic = true ,  
        lazer.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false  ,  
        lazer.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false .  These are my physics properties related to gravity

Comment: You don't tell us how you shot `lazer`, or we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Edit your question for future update rather than commenting.

Answer (score 0):

```
laser.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
```

Comment: this makes me not able to push the node when tapping on the screen, i have already tried this